# What's the best way of using hash tags for page navigation as well as anchor navigation?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, hashtag

I'm making a web application that uses hash tags for page navigation like this

```
http://foo.bar.com/#pages/home
```

I just realized that one of my pages is going to be kind of **huge**, containing it's own tree-structured menu with links that should scroll the page to different anchor tags in the page. Obviously I can't use actual hash tags for that now, since they are busy. I'm going to have to use a programmatic solution with an URL like this

```
http://foo.bar.com/#pages/home/section
```

Or would it be possible to use more than one hash symbol, perhaps changing it to this?

```
http://foo.bar.com/#!/pages/home#section
```

But how can this be done programmatically anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd scrap [the broken use of hashbangs](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs), switch to using [the history API](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider) instead and give serious consideration to the question of *"If **that** much content is being replaced, is loading it via Ajax really providing a benefit?"*

Answer (score 1):

Your Question does  not seem clear to me,

If  your page is too large, you could go for pagination using AJAX and PHP, for more
http://www.codediesel.com/php/simple-pagination-in-php/

or http://www.99points.info/2011/01/ajax-pagination-using-jquery-and-php-with-animation/

Other wise, if you still want things to be in URL #tags, then you can go with it.
I doubt you could give  something like this "`http://foo.bar.com/#pages/home/` "

You could also try URL rewriting http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html